# How to change what account Firefox prefills when logging in using a dialog?

Tags: firefox, http

(Not exactly sure about the terminology here but I am referring to when you log in using a separate small modal/floating window (on Macs, it is a "sheet" that appears as a drop down menu) rather than a regular web form)

At home and at work I connect to a web server 10.0.0.1 that requires me to log in. I have saved the login details for both accounts (they are not the same) but Firefox insists on always prefilling this drop-down/pop-up window with the login details for work. On regular web form log ins (like here on Superuser), if you click in the field Firefox shows a list of all logins it think matches that specific form but I can't find that option when the login is through one of those popup dialogs.

Is there a way to select which login details to use in HTTP Dialogs in Firefox?

Update: image of the dialog.

[image]

Comment: Is this an issue for you caused by the change where Firefox now shows other subdomains https://superuser.com/questions/1515124/firefox-started-showing-a-list-of-passwords-instead-of-a-single-one-how-can-i-m or is it a separate issue? Is it possible to provide a screenshot example of one of these modals?

Comment: @MC10 Added an image. No it is not the same.